# r'\textbf{}'.format() doesn't work for string variable with Latex in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, format, latex

Hi I'm trying to enable bold font for labels in Matplotlib with Latex text rendering. I am able to do this for numerical variables (integers, floats) but failed with string variable.

So this works:

```
a = 1
plt.plot(X, y, label=r'\textbf{}'.format(a))
```

but this doesn't:

```
a = 'text'
plt.plot(X, y, label=r'\textbf{}'.format(a))
```

I know I can do this:

```
plt.plot(X, y, label=r'\textbf{text}')
```

But how can I use the format for a string variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the curly brackets of the latex command, since the `.format` function uses those brackets to determine where to put its argument in the text.

Consider e.g.

```
r'\textbf{}'.format("something")
```

which results in

```
"\textbfsomething"
```

This is of course no valid latex command. On the other hand

```
r'\textbf{}'.format(9)
```

results in

```
"\textbf9"
```

which **is** a valid latex command. To be on the save side, always escape all curly brackets.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
a = 1
plt.plot([1,2], [2,3], label=r'\textbf{{{}}}'.format(a))

a = 'text'
plt.plot([1,2], [1,2], label=r'\textbf{{{}}}'.format(a))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works! Do I always need to have three curly braces to do this?

Comment: If you want to use the `.format` formatting for latex strings, yes, those curly brackets are inevitable.